# Where can I see sonar.analysis key/value pairs?

Tags: sonarqube

According to the [documentation](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/analysis-parameters/) I configured a sonar.analysis key/value pair, just as shown in the example `sonar.analysis.buildNumber=12345`.

In SonarQube, is there a view which shows this detail of the analysis context?

Maybe related: For a pull request analysis where can I see the date of the analysis? Can I see the history of PR analysis?